# Jetty Server throwing connection timeout exception

Tags: java, rest, http, jetty

I am trying to put my application on an aws server but I am getting this log in my Jetty Server log.

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out
May 12, 2015 1:41:02 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
```

I am making an HTTPS request to another service from inside my server code like this and it works perfectly on my local dev machine.

```
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://someresource.com/");

    String response="";
    try{
        client.executeMethod(method);
        response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
```

But it fails with the logged messages I posted above. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Also I simply took the war file of my artifact and put it in the webapps dir and am running Jetty with this command

```
sudo java -jar start.jar --disable=deploy
```

Comment: it seems that on the aws machine it's not possible to connect to `someresource.com`; could be some AWS configuration issue?

Comment: Omg, why did I not think of that, thanks a lot :). I added an outbound rule for https on that instance.

Comment: What is `--disable=deploy` ?  that's not a valid command line for Jetty's start.jar

Comment: Its for disabling auto-deploy I think. I had read that somewhere.